# Click on image, load google image search

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make it so when a user clicks on a image in the content of my website, it will then load that image into google image search and display the results.

This is the code I am using

```
<script>
  var gurl = "http://www.google.com/searchbyimage?sbisrc=cr_1_3_2&amp;image_url=";

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.thefeed').delegate('p img', 'click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.open(gurl + this.src, '_blank');
    });
  });
</script>
```

and a html snippet

```
<p>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg">
</p>
```

The idea is for when you click on the image, it would open up [this page.](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZisRJJ22PcrwYsGUgjQy2HSIld5q7Y1WKI3e2WOOsC_1cdw8wlt1xCtinkwQp0dJxaDRO7EIH9tAOEHTH-HZnbuzsQc0TmiBw2ihG3WwmqXuO0D45107I_1DGmt8fMKAK03d1zzS_1GX9leNik-eZDt9lBgPKrJacivz2SPDNRnhSzRKRlKlUnaAiarfqMq9P6LCM_1inHdQDUKqYkw0hIzWk2YwmmbJN90x0FMVoZpzPrzru2ASh7BbCxIhGu8BbroJK5OHk6SzroZQ_1mEg-b32xearzuwz3rl_18eNLJB56KE3Z8vZzw93I8fQ2PBl5iv8TIlR2d9QhIL2P2B-MmUHdZqRkiLxYYQ&hl=en)

Comment: So, what's the question here?

Comment: It isn't working, I can't click on the image.

Comment: Please post your complete HTML.

Comment: @31piy
This is on a wordpress site which is automatically wrapping the img in a <p> tag.
So more or less it would be 
'  <div id="container">
      <div class="thefeed">
            POST LOOP
      </div>
      </div>'

Comment: Do you receive any error in console?

Comment: JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).delegate is not a function TypeError: $(...).delegate is not a function

Comment: This is an issue with `jqMigrate`. The jQuery library is not being loaded into your browser.

Comment: @31piy Yeah man, my stupidity, figured out the issue with that right after i posted it here, now onto the next issue.,.. haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var gurl = "http://www.google.com/searchbyimage?sbisrc=cr_1_3_2&image_url=";
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.thefeed').delegate('p img', 'click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                // Check if click is on image
                if (e.currentTarget.tagName === 'IMG') {
                    window.open(gurl + e.currentTarget.src, '_blank');   
                }
            });
        });
```

One thing is that google is rewriting the url and we cannot stop that from this code. This would correctly generate the url for you now.

this was pointing to `.thefeed` in this case which should be now resolved

Pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eRExWW

Comment: what do you mean by won't allow me to actually click on the image? i tried clicking on the image and it generated the correct url for me when i tried consoling `gurl + e.currentTarget.src,`

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RgZvwY i can click on the image and it is opening a new tab with correct url alerted, can u check and let me know your problem in the pen?

Comment: in your example, when you click on the image it will load but then take you to https://www.google.com/imghp?sbi=1 I want it to take me to the page I used in the first post.

Comment: that is not possible, google is redirecting from server side which you cannot prevent.

Comment: ur gurl is wrong `var gurl = "http://www.google.com/searchbyimage?sbisrc=cr_1_3_2&image_url="` fixed the issue. updated the answer

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer.